# Authenticate parameters and redirecting to authenticated parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport-local

I was trying to make an app that has different users. The users could login and  view and manipulate the same data. I figure why make a whole different documents for each user with the same data when I could just make a list of user objects and authenticate on that. I want to set up routes that looks like `users/user1` `users/user2`. user 1 cant just go to the url bar and change `user1` to `user2` I'm having problems trying make it so that users cant access the url by just changing it by typing.

so I have a document with a list of users like this:

```
{ list: 'userList',
  users:
   [ { password: 'pass1', username: 'user1' },
     { username: 'user2', password: 'pass2' },
     { username: 'user3', password: 'pass3' } ],
  address: '14453 ny 14456',
  desc: '3 floors',
  __v: 0,
  _id: 56baf181356641f01213295a }
```

I have passport set up like this

```
passport.use("local", new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
        User.findOne({ "users": { $elemMatch :{username : username}} }, function(err, user){
            // console.log("user " + user)
            if(err){return done(err);}
            if(!user){
                console.log("no user")
                return done(null, false,{message : "Incorrect username."});
            }
            if(!user.validPassword( username, password)){
                return done(null, false,{message : "Incorrect password."});
            }
            return done(null, user)
        })
    }))
```

This the part where I feel like I'm real stupid. on the `users/:name` there is a form and when they submit the form I want the user to be redirected back to `users/:name`. I understand how to do that. but I was trying to fix up the the part by having the user only be able to view their url by adding a counter and if that counter was less than 1 set the name to the variable `name` so `name` couldn't be assigned anymore. so you could compare the name only once. It's all messed up.

**basically I need to be directed to the original url (`users/:name`) when the user submits the form. The user shouldn't be able to delete user1(:name) in the url bar and type in user2. He has to log in himself**

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res, next){
    console.log("posted")
    passport.authenticate("local",{
        successRedirect : "/users/" + req.body.username,
        failureRedirect : "/login",
        failureFlash : true
    })(req, res, next)
} )
var counter = 0
app.get("/users/:name",  ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.params.name)
    counter++;
    if(counter <= 1){
        var name = req.params.name
    }

    User.findOne({"users" : { $elemMatch: { username : name}}}, function(err, doc){
        if(!doc){
            res.redirect("../login")
            counter = 0;
        } else{

            console.log("test ", doc);
            var users = doc.users;
            var currentUser = {};

            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
                if(users[i].username === name){
                    currentUser = users[i];
                }
            }
            console.log("currentUser ", currentUser)
            if(currentUser.username === name ){
                res.render("users", {result : doc, user : currentUser.username});
            }           
        }


    })

})

app.post("/users", function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + req.originalUrl )
    // console.log(req.body.subject, " " ,  req.protocol , " ", req.get("host") , " " ,  req.originalUrl)
    res.redirect("back")
    // res.redirect(req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + req.originalUrl + req.params.name)
})
```

jade:

```
html
    head
    body
        p Welcome #{user}
        p= result.address
        h3= result.desc
        a(href="/logout") logout
        form(action = "/users" method = "POST")
            label delete:
            input(type = "text" name="subject")
            input(type="submit" value = "delete")
```